# How long does it take Google to index an SO answer?

Tags: discussion

In your experience, how long does it take Google to index an SO question/answer?

Answer (score 8):

In my experience less than 5 minutes.  Many times I have begun to answer a question and Google a part of it and the first result of my search is the question itself.

Answer (score 5):

You can do test.

Look to newest question on SO (SF and SU) and try finding on google :)

---

I do test and result is 30 min.